# .animate to one element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m doing an animation hover using this function:

```
    function lookbookhover(){
        var lookbook = $('.lookbook_info')
        lookbook.bind({
            'mouseenter' : function(){
                lookbook_animate(200)
            },
            'mouseleave' : function(){
                lookbook_animate(30)
            }
        })
    }
    function lookbook_animate(h){
        $('.lookbook_info').animate({
            height: h
        }, 300 );
    }
```

The problem I have is that when the user hovers one item (.lookbook_info) it animates all the others .lookbook_info that are on the page, how can I point to just animate just one element?

I know it´s using $(this) but I haven´t get the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the element to the function:

```
function lookbookhover(){
    $('.lookbook_info').on({
        mouseenter : function(){
            lookbook_animate(this, 200);
        },
        mouseleave : function(){
            lookbook_animate(this, 30);
        }
    });
}
function lookbook_animate(elem, h){
    $(elem).stop(true,true).animate({
        height: h
    }, 300 );
}
```

[**DEMONSTRATION**](http://jsfiddle.net/juxEG/)

Comment: Could you explain to me what the `h` variable means?/How it is defined?

Comment: `h` is the number passed to the function, used to set the height in the animation, just like in the question ?

Comment: mmm sorry but this doesn´t work, it doesn´t give me console error but still don´t show the hover info

Comment: @fxg - of course it works? Just added  a demonstration as proof, you must be doing something else wrong. Did you call the function, and did you use a document.ready function etc.

Comment: adeneo, any idea why when you hover over the item quickly it starts to bounce like crazy? is there any solution you know to that?

Comment: Yeah, try fiddling with the stop() function, read the documentation on the jQuery site for stop() first. Also, placement can sometimes do this, like position, margins and other stuff. You just have to figure out something that works on your site, as it all depends on a lot of different thing etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this)` if you want to point that element on which event occured or if you want to select specific elements such as maybe first, last, or nth-child:

```
$(element:first)

$(element:last)

$(element:nth-child(2))
```

You need to pass `this` as argument to that function.

Comment: how can I pass the argument "this" to that function?

Comment: @fxg man i can also make jQuery but i thought it will be effective way ;) rather writing a 20 lines of JS.